# Python initializing several arrays with output of loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

So i am relativley new to python (using Python 3 with the Spyder IDE 3.8).
I am having the following main calculation file, where several functions come together and are looped through. Now i am trying to evaluate with a grade function if the single values for spray_pressure, spray_angle and particle_size are in the given borders. If not a 0 goes to a new array, if yes the actual value is stored in the new array.
So i want to store all the outputs in 4 new arrays spray_pressure, spray_angle, particle_size and massflow. But i dont now how to initialize them and proper store the values.
As you can see the output of this script sould be 4 arrays spray_pressure, spray_angle, particle_size and massflow and each with the size [105, 35] so that further plots and calculations can be made based on those arrays.

I tried `np.array(len(no_düsenkombination ), len(no_hours_Process)` but that doesnt work because i need a [105x35] array and np.array seems to be limited to 32 entries. If somebody knows a good solution i would really appreciate that. I have been trying to figure it out now the whole day.

````
from calc_particlesize import calc_particlesize
from calc_sprayangle import calc_sprayangle
from calc_spraypressure import calc_spraypressure
from evaluation import evaluation

def calc_processfactor(df_düsenkombinationen, mk, process_duration, df_rezeptur, recipe_nr):
        
    number_of_nozzles = 6
    k = 0 #increment mass flow kondensat
    index_Zero = 0
    grade = 0
    mkmax = mk/(number_of_nozzles*3600)
    
    no_düsenkombination = 105

    no_hours_Process = 35
    
    delta_massKondensat = 0
        
    for i in range(no_düsenkombination):
        for j in range(no_hours_Process):
             
            # deltamk[index_Zero,j] = mkmax[j,index_Zero]/100
            
            massflow = np.zeros(len(no_düsenkombination), len(no_hours_Process))
            delta_massKondensat = mkmax/100
            mk = mkmax 
            
            while grade != 1 and mk > 0:
               
                mk = mkmax-k*delta_massKondensat                                       #mass kondensat max ist reduziert bis grade                                                     #oder mk = 0 ist
                spray_pressure = calc_spraypressure(mk,df_düsenkombinationen.iloc[0:5,i:i+1])                                                #Berechnung des Sprühdruckes
                spray_pressure_eff = spray_pressure
                spray_angle = calc_sprayangle(spray_pressure, df_rezeptur, recipe_nr, df_düsenkombinationen)                         #Berechnung des Sprüwinkels
                spray_angle_eff = spray_angle
                particle_size = calc_particlesize(spray_pressure,spray_angle, mk, recipe_nr, df_rezeptur, df_düsenkombinationen)      #Berechnung der Partikelgrösse
                particle_size_eff = particle_size
                grade = evaluation(spray_pressure,spray_angle,particle_size)                                  #Bewertung der Prozessgrössen
                k = k+1

            if grade == 0:
                spray_pressure[i,j] = 0         #INTIIALISIEREN      #Matrix mit Sprühdruck, Zeile: Kombiantionen, Spalte: Stunden
                spray_angle[i,j]= 0          #Matrix mit Sprühwinkel, Zeile: Kombiantionen, Spalte: Stunden
                particle_size[i,j]= 0        #Matrix mit Partikelgrösse, Zeile: Kombiantionen, Spalte: Stunden
                massflow[i,j]= 0            #Matrix mit Konzentratmassenstrom, Zeile: Kombiantionen, Spalte: Stunden
            else:
                spray_pressure[i,j] =  spray_pressure_eff
                spray_angle[i,j]= spray_angle_eff
                particle_size[i,j] = particle_size_eff
                massflow[i,j] = mk*6*3600
                grade = 0                      #Reset von grade

        
    return(spray_pressure, spray_angle, particle_size, massflow)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The only real size limitations to an `np.array` would be the amount of memory you've got available. Though there may be other errors in your code, I suspect the issue is:

```
np.zeros(len(no_düsenkombination), len(no_hours_Process))
```

which should be:

```
np.zeros([no_düsenkombination, no_hours_Process])
```

to get a 105x35 matrix of zeros.

Comment: if i do that python gives me "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"

Comment: Edited the code. I read up higher to see that those variables are just integers and so you don't want the length of anything.